# configure tab width rendering with `git commit --verbose`

Tags: git, vim, command-line-interface

currently `git commit --verbose` renders 8 spaces for me, how can i have it either 2 or 4 spaces instead, or a tab character?

my `.zshrc` has it setup so that cat/less/more all output tabs as two:

```
tabs -2
export LESS="--tabs=2 -R"
export MORE="--tabs=2 -R"
```

vim is setup to show tabs with a width of 2, it's what `git commit` opens via git's core.editor config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git commit --verbose` renders a diff and if your code uses tabs, then Git will render tabs in the diff.  The general rule is that a diff can be applied to another codebase to apply the specific changes, and so it would be incorrect to render diffs with spaces instead of tabs.

If you're using Vim and your `.vimrc` enables filetype plugins, then the `gitcommit` filetype plugin sets `tabstop` to 8.  This is likely because Git includes text indented with tabs in your commit messages and it will look odd if you have a different setting.  However, if you want, uou can override this by putting something like the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit  setl ts=2
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thanks so much for the explanation!